# Flutter google sign in only when user exist in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using two packages for firebase authorization:

1. [google_sign_in ^4.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)
2. [firebase_auth ^0.16.1](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)

When I call a sign in method

```
final FirebaseUser user =
        (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```

It creates a user in the firebase authorization table. Is there a way to check if a user with this social provider data exists and if he doesn't exist then refuse authorization? I mean only the google sign in method.

Comment: @JideGuru thanks for answer, would you explain in details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html) to determine the sign-in methods that were used to sign in with the email address in the credentials. If that includes a `google.com` sign-in method, the user signed in with this account to the Google provider before.

---

But note that this won't stop the user from calling the `signInWithCredential` API themselves. So while you can use this approach to optimize the UI flow for the user, you can't prevent that a malicious user still creates an account in your Firebase project.

This is inherent to the nature of client-side authentication: you can't keep the user from proving who they are. What you **can** do however is limit what they have access to. If you're using Firebase back-end services to store the data for your app, this is accomplished by using Firebase's [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to control what data a user can access.